# ActiveRecord: deleting associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Something I'm not getting...

I have this in my model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :model_options # a link table for many to many
    has_many :options, 
             :through => :model_options, 
             :dependent => :destroy, 
             :foreign_key => 'model_id'
end
```

And I try to do this:

```
model = Model.find(id)
model.options.delete # also tried model.options.delete_all
```

But this is not deleting the records from the DB.
Instead I'm having to do this:

```
model.options.each do |option|
   option.delete
end
```

...which can't be the best way.
So what is the best way, please?

Answer (score 10):

```
model.options.clear
```

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001789)

Answer (score 4):

Garry is right:
    model.options.clear

But you can go further and associate it with a model callback, if it fits your needs

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :model_options # a link table for many to many
has_many :options, 
         :through => :model_options, 
         :dependent => :destroy, 
         :foreign_key => 'model_id'

# Clear options records before destroy
before_destroy :clear_options

protected
  def clear_options
    options.clear
  end
end
```

Or you can use [this plugin](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/foreign_key_migrations) to enforce FK relationships from the database adding DB triggers (if your particular db flavour supports them) appropiately.

I hope that maight help you

Comment: Curious, is the before_destroy callback necessary if you have the :dependent => :destroy option in place?

Comment: Nope. It's not starting Rails 3.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3 all you have to do is `:dependent => :destroy` and ActiveRecord will take care of the rest